# keystore was not valid(corona sdk)

Tags: android, build, sdk, coronasdk

I builded a game in corona sdk and when I want to build my game to android 
after it says:

```
D:\Corona SDK\Resources\debug.keystore was not valid
```

What can I do for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used Corona SDK, however seems like you are using the wrong user/password for your `debug.keystore` file.

The default user/password for the `debug.keystore` is **android/android**, unless you have already changes those values.